# How to display JavaScript variables in a HTML page without document.write

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display some JavaScript variable on my HTML page.

I was first using `document.write()` but it use to overwrite the current page when the function was called.

After searching around, the general consensus was that `document.write()` isn't liked very much. What are the other options?

I found a page suggesting using `.innerHTML` but that was written in 2005.

A jsFiddle illustrating my problem http://jsfiddle.net/xHk5g/

Comment: It would have been nice, if you had provided us with some sample.

Comment: Using `innerHTML` is still the easiest way. You can also create a text node and append it to the target node.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

`Element.innerHTML` is pretty much the way to go. Here are a few ways to use it:

#### HTML

```html
<div class="results"></div>
```

#### JavaScript

```js
// 'Modern' browsers (IE8+, use CSS-style selectors)
document.querySelector('.results').innerHTML = 'Hello World!';

// Using the jQuery library
$('.results').html('Hello World!');
```

If you just want to update a portion of a `<div>` I usually just add an empty element with a class like `value` or one I want to replace the contents of to the main `<div>`. e.g.

```html
<div class="content">Hello <span class='value'></span></div>
```

Then I'd use some code like this:

```js
// 'Modern' browsers (IE8+, use CSS-style selectors)
document.querySelector('.content .value').innerHTML = 'World!';

// Using the jQuery library
$(".content .value").html("World!");
```

Then the HTML/DOM would now contain:

```html
<div class="content">Hello <span class='value'>World!</span></div>
```

#### Full example. Click run snippet to try it out.

```js
// Plain Javascript Example
var $jsName = document.querySelector('.name');
var $jsValue = document.querySelector('.jsValue');

$jsName.addEventListener('input', function(event){
  $jsValue.innerHTML = $jsName.value;
}, false);


// JQuery example
var $jqName = $('.name');
var $jqValue = $('.jqValue');

$jqName.on('input', function(event){
  $jqValue.html($jqName.val());
});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 1em 0 0.25em 0;
}

input[type=text] {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.jsValue, .jqValue {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Setting HTML content example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- This <input> field is where I'm getting the name from -->
  <label>Enter your name: <input class="name" type="text" value="World"/></label>
  
  <!-- Plain Javascript Example -->
  <h1>Plain Javascript Example</h1>Hello <span class="jsValue">World</span>
  
  <!-- jQuery Example -->
  <h1>jQuery Example</h1>Hello <span class="jqValue">World</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: isn't innerHtml replaces the entire html part inside an html element instead of just the text? I think the OP was referring to just displaying some JS variables on the page.

Comment: @Ajai: So does your solution. Obviously one would create an element whose only purpose is to contain that value.

Comment: @FelixKling: Actually not. My Solution just replaces the text part of the div. What happens if I want to display the value just inside FirstDiv in my solution and still want the FirstDiv hold the second div element? Would innerHtml just replace the value inside FirstDiv and not remove SecondDiv?  I am just asking

Comment: The jQuery solution is working for me displaying the contents of the variable within a div.

Comment: @Ajai: `.text()` also replaces the whole content of the element, but it interprets the argument as plain text instead of HTML (see the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2)). All these methods (`.innerHTML`, `.html()` and `.text()`) replace the content of the element. If you want to add text, you'd have to use one of the insertion methods (`append`, `insertBefore`, etc (jQuery)).

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks for the insight. Will check it though.

Comment: In general it is best just to do `innerHTML`/`.html()` to an element that is empty or you want to replace. See the example I added.

Comment: Loved the technique used to update a portion of div using span !! This is exactly I as looking for. @pseudosavant

Comment: this example is useful for costant, but if I use var s="Subho" then how can I show this value of s in a <span id="name"></span>??

Comment: @Subho I'm not sure I'm understanding your question. Are you asking how to put `s` into `<span id="name"></span>` when `var s = "Subho"`? If that is the case you can just use the `#name` id selector like this: `$("#name").html(s);`.

Comment: Can someone provide a self-contained, autonomously-working example? I know my way around many software technologies (Linux, C, C++, Python, etc), but not javascript and HTML (yes, that's weird). I don't know how all the above things fit together (in a single file, perhaps?) running on a vanilla Apache webserver.

Comment: @JohnnyUtahh Check out the snippet I added. There is a plain Javascript and a jQuery example.

Comment: @pseudosavant - You. Totally. Rock. Thanks!

Comment: Appreciate the answer. Really helps me alot!

Comment: How can I use such a JS variable as the value for `filename=""` for a download link?

Comment: That is really a different question than what this is about. You should try posting it as an actual question.

Answer (score 15):

You can use javascript to access elements on the page and modify their contents. So for example you might have a page with some HTML markup like so:

```
<div id="MyEdit">
    This text will change
</div>
```

You can use javascript to change the content like so...

```
document.getElementById("MyEdit").innerHTML = "My new text!";​
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/nQD3h/)

---

You can also look at using the [JQuery javascript library](http://jquery.com/) for DOM manipulation, it has some great features to make things like this very easy.

For example, with JQuery, you could do this to acheive the same result...

```
$("#MyEdit").html("My new text!");
```

[Here is a working example of the JQuery version](http://jsfiddle.net/7YCE8/)

---

Based on [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/xHk5g/) you provided in your post. The following JQuery would work for you:

```
var x = "hello wolrd";
$("p").html(x);
```

[Here is the working version](http://jsfiddle.net/QQGfc/)

Using a `P` tag like this however is not recommended. You would ideally want to use an element with a unique ID so you can ensure you are selecting the correct one with JQuery.

Comment: @AndyE: Yes I spotted that... too much JQuery for me ;)

Comment: @musefan i almost wrote the same thing when typing my answer! i don't know how people live without jQuery :P

Comment: `document.getElementById("MyEdit").innerHtml("My new text!");` should be as
`document.getElementById("MyEdit").innerHtml="My new text!";`

Answer (score 5):

there are different ways of doing this.
one way would be to write a script retrieving a command.
like so:

```
var name="kieran";
document.write=(name);
```

or we could use the default JavaScript way to print it.

```
var name="kieran";
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=name;

and the html code would be: 

<p id="output"></p>
```

i hope this helped :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use jquery to get hold of the html element that you want to load the value with.

Say for instance if your page looks something like this,

```
<div id="FirstDiv">
  <div id="SecondDiv">
     ...
  </div>
 </div>
```

And if your javascript (I hope) looks something as simple as this,

```
function somefunction(){
  var somevalue = "Data to be inserted";
  $("#SecondDiv").text(somevalue);
}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

innerHTML is fine and still valid. Use it all the time on projects big and small. I just flipped to an open tab in my IDE and there was one right there.

```
 document.getElementById("data-progress").innerHTML = "<img src='../images/loading.gif'/>";
```

Not much has changed in js + dom manipulation since 2005, other than the addition of more libraries. You can easily set other properties such as

```
   uploadElement.style.width = "100%";
```

Comment: `appendChild` expects a DOM node, not a string.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid innerHTML you can use the DOM methods to construct elements and append them to the page.

```
​var element = document.createElement('div');
var text = document.createTextNode('This is some text');
element.appendChild(text);
document.body.appendChild(element);​​​​​​
```

Comment: Weird, this seems to be the most relevant answer to the OP question. Although it's JAVASCRIPT and not jQuery, it can be 'portable' avoiding to add extra container in html.

Answer (score 1):

hi here is a simple example: `<div id="test">content</div>` and

```
var test = 5;
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = test;
```

and you can test it here : http://jsfiddle.net/SLbKX/

Answer (score 0):

Add an element to your page (such as a div) and write to that div.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <header>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </header>

    <body>
        <div id="myDiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#myDiv').text('hello world!');
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = 'hello world!';
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to above, but I used (this was in CSHTML):

JavaScript:

```
var value = "Hello World!"<br>
$('.output').html(value);
```

CSHTML:

```
<div class="output"></div>
```