# Concatenate HTML String

Tags: html, django, variables, object, concatenation

I want to concatenate a HTML string. I'm building a modifiable url (not for the page, but for an internal api).

I'm using Django [if that helps]

```
urldata = "http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=" + {{specificMedia.channel}}
```

I'm trying to add the first section which is a string to the "{{specificMedia.channel}}" which is also a string. and set it to a object variable

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
     data= urldata
```

Is this possible without using Javascript?

If I have to use javascript, how do I access a javascript string variable outside of the script?

thanks

**REVISED QUESTION**
So, I now know that it is not possible in HTML, but I want to simulate an HTML string. How do I do this in java script?

I want to make:
    data = 'someRandomString'

could I do something like?

```
<script> var z = 'someRandomString'; </script>

data = <script type = "text/javascript">document.write(x); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to use Javascript. HTML is a markup language and cannot do calculations. (Eg. `string1 + string2`). As for the second question, I'm not sure.

Comment: Go over to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689109/how-to-display-javascript-variables-in-a-html-page-without-document-write

Comment: If i read your question corectly this question is very simaler.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i found at the link:
You can use javascript to access elements on the page and modify their contents. So for example you might have a page with some HTML markup like so:

'This text will change'

You can use javascript to change the content like so...

document.getElementById("MyEdit").innerHTML = "My new text!";​

Comment: While I followed the link and I see how there's works, I tried to clone it and use my strings and it failed. I posted another question with my full code, so hopefully I can get a working solution. Thanks for your help