# JavaScript to print on Screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to Javascript, I want my variable to be printed on the webpage, but not using `<span>` and `innerHTML`

```
var pProductCode = $('[name=pProductCode]').val();
$('input[id*="_IP/PA_N_"]').each(function(i){
ipPAAmt += Number(convertToNumber($(this).val()));
});
```

How can I do that?

Comment: where you want to print? in console means use `console.log(ipPAAmt)` in alert means use `alert(ipPAAmt)` In html means use `$('#yourElementID').html(ipPAAmt);`

Comment: Please explain your problem...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689109/how-to-display-javascript-variables-in-a-html-page-without-document-write

Comment: off topic.. to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more detailed answers that apply to your situation at:
 [How to display javascript variables in a html page without document.write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689109/how-to-display-javascript-variables-in-a-html-page-without-document-write)

Basically you want to create an html element and then replace the contents with your variable.

Comment: Avoid just linking to other answers. You have identified a duplicate question, and it should be flagged as such. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689109/how-to-display-javascript-variables-in-a-html-page-without-document-write

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to figure out how but didn't have the rep to do it at the time. I do now so I will make sure to do so from now on.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#yourDivID').html(ipPAAmt);
```