# Display javascript variable in html body

Tags: javascript, html

here is my approximate code:

```
 <script> 
function smth(){........}
    var name = smth('fullname');
 var hobby = smth('hobby');

    </script>
```

I need to display it normally in the html body. However, every way I tried gave me an alert window or it simply didn't work. I didn't find the similar solution.
I know that the way above gives an alert windows as well, but I just wanted to show you the way I get my variables.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `document.write(name);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689109/how-to-display-javascript-variables-in-a-html-page-without-document-write)

Answer (score 1):

So you want to *append* some *text* to `<body>`?

```
function smth(str) {
    return document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
}
```

This is making use of the following *DOM Methods*

- [`node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)
- [`document.createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) (or [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement))

Please notice that it won't introduce formatting (such as line brakes `<br />`), if you want those you'd need to add them too.

Comment: Thank you!  could you be specific please

Answer (score 1):

With this approach you can target an element by ID and insert whatever you like inside it, but the solution suggested from Paul S is more simple and clean.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myVar = 42;
            function displayMyVar(targetElementId) {
                document.getElementById(targetElementId).innerHTML = myVar;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="displayMyVar('target');">
        <span id="target"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it works..partly, as first I still get the alert window!

Comment: What do you mean with alert window?

Comment: My bad, I mean a pop up

Comment: You are probably calling the "alert()" function somewhere in your code

Answer (score 1):

One of the very common ways to do this is using `innerHTML`. Suppose you declare a `<p>` in the `<body>` as output, then you can write:

```
<script> function smth(){........}
var name=smth('fullname');
var hobby=smth('hobby')
var out=document.getElementById("output");
out.innerHTML=name; (or you may write hobby)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
var yourvar='value';
document.body.innerHTML = yourvar;
```