# Why my web application does not redirect correctly?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jwt

I am trying to pass an attribute from a java servlet to jsp and write this attribute on jsp file. However it does not redirect to jsp file url but it writes the content of the jsp file. Here is my related codes:

Control.java:

```
@WebServlet("/Control")
public class Control extends HttpServlet{

@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Key key = MacProvider.generateKey();
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try{
        String jwt = Jwts.builder()
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, key)
                .setSubject("username")
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(time))
                .setExpiration(new Date(time+6000000))
                .claim("password","password")
                .compact();
        req.setAttribute("jwt", jwt);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/Home.jsp").forward(req,resp);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Home.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
${jwt}
</body>
</html>
```

Here, browser stays on `http://localhost:8080/Control` but it writes the content of Home.jsp file which is just a java web token result string.

2) My second question is when I tryed to store this jwt result string in browser local storage and then write it in jsp file in order to check if it stored in browser or not. But it does not prints anything. To do this, I just changed the `Home.jsp` file as follow:

(I took both of the code snippets from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858456/how-to-display-a-javascript-var-in-html-body))

Home.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    localStorage.setItem("jwt", ${jwt});
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("jwt"));
    var jjwt = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
    document.write(jjwt);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Another try:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    localStorage.setItem("jwt", ${jwt});
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("jwt"));
    var jjwt = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
    document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = jjwt;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<span id="myText"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1) When you use RequestDispatcher.forward(request,response), your servlet will still have control but your jsp page will be loaded so this is nothing to worry about.
If you want your browser URL to show your JSP page URL, do `response.sendRedirect("URL TO LOAD");`

2)Since you are using JSP, try accessing the request variables like below and print it

```
<% String jwt = (String) request.getAttribute("jwt");%>
```

We need to set it as

```
localStorage.setItem('jwt', <%=jwt%>);
```

Comment: The first one is okey, but in the second one I just want to store a variable in local storage with using js and then taking back to see if it stored correctly or not.

Comment: And if I use "response.sendRedirect", I can not pass attribute with req.setAttribute. So how can I pass attribute while using "response.sendRedirect"?

Comment: you cannot pass request attributes to your jsp when redirecting

Comment: You can use <%= to access JSP variables. So you can store it in a variable and use that to store it in local storage

Comment: Try this:                                                                
    localStorage.setItem("jwt", <%=jwt%>);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("jwt"));
    var jjwt = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
    document.write(jjwt);

Comment: maybe you need to try referring to the window object explicitly
 - window.localStorage.setItem

Comment: Actually just putting ' ' these solved it. ('<%= jwt %>) If you write the above comment whic starts with "try this", or just update this answer, I will accept it. Thanks