# How do I output a variable from Javascript to html?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to inject text into a div using a variable. Here's a Stack Snippet of my code:

```js
tDNA() {
  var dna = prompt("Enter the DNA: ");
}
document.getElementById("dna").innerHTML = "DNA: " + dna;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <src="main.js">
    <div id="dna"></div>
</body>

</html>


function promp
```

Comment: "src" is not an element. You want to be using <script src="main.js"></script> to load your main.js file. And you need to do something to actually fire the promptDNA function and you need to move the document.getElementById.... into that function as well.

Comment: your dna is being used out of scope

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858456/how-to-display-a-javascript-var-in-html-body

Comment: Besides, you should use [element.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/textContent) instead of `innerHTML`. Using `innerHTML` for user input is an XSS vulnerabiliy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to display a javascript var in html body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858456/how-to-display-a-javascript-var-in-html-body)

Answer (score 1):

You need to import your script like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: `type="text/javascript"` is not required, and even not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Like this, you have to add the data to the HTML where the variable `dna` is in scope and then actually call the function

```js
function promptDNA(){
    var dna = prompt("Enter the DNA: ");
    document.getElementById("dna").textContent = "DNA: " + dna;
}

promptDNA()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dna"></div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, you're importing your script improperly.

Comment: I also had to add "onload = "promptDNA()" to get it to work, thanks for the help!

Comment: Your script is executed before the DOM is initialized. You need to wait for the DOM to initialize or use the script tag at the end of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script defer src = "main.js"></script>
    <div id = "dna">
      <p></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function promptDNA(){
    var dna = prompt("Enter the DNA: ");
    d1 = document.querySelector("p");   
    d1.textContent = dna;
}

promptDNA();
```

Comment: Your script is executed before the DOM is initialized. You need to wait for the DOM to initialize or use the script tag at the end of the HTML.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 Added defer in script tag.