# How to add HTML to the text and add it to the DOM to display it?

Tags: html, css, dom

I have this text:

```
var text = "some instructions";
```

I want to set to the text some style and then I want to put it to DOM.
So  I have tried this:

```
var text = '"<font size="6">This is some text!</font>"';
```

But I am not getting the desired result. The text is not changed and I getting html tags being displayed as text.

Any idea on how to add html to the text and then add it to the `DOM`?

Comment: you are using javascript right

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858456/how-to-display-a-javascript-var-in-html-body

Comment: You need to show how you insert the text into the DOM. And please don't use <font> anymore – it's been deprecated since the late 1990s.

Comment: Assigning a string to a variable will not add it to the DOM.

Comment: You should inject this as a html content not text content.

Answer (score 1):

Use `innerHTML` on the element where you want to add the html

```
var text = "<div style='color:red;'>abc</div>";
document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this to create a DOM Element with text .

```
var texttag= document.createElement('text');//create DOM 
var text= document.createTextNode("Please Select Program Course"); //Create Your Text 
texttag.setAttribute("for", "Please Select Program Course"); //Create DOM Attributes
texttag.appendChild(text); //append the text into DOM
```

that is it ..