# How to concatenate JavaScript variable in HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to concatenate a javascript variable into a paragraph tag in html. Don't know how or if this is possible. please help, thanks.

I've tried `${timePassed}` and `+'timePassed'`

```
<body><p>Congratulations! You won! Would you like to restart?<div class="restart">
    <i class="fa fa-repeat"></i>
</div>Your time was + 'timePassed'</p></body>
```

It's not implying the variable `timePassed` into the paragraph tag.

Comment: where's your full code?

Comment: Why are you putting `div` inside a `p` element? This is an invalid HTML

Comment: Yes, I know that. I am doing it since the div has a class that invokes a restart function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to display a javascript var in html body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858456/how-to-display-a-javascript-var-in-html-body)

Comment: The full code is about 800+ lines of code. Didn't want to put all of it here

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a `<div>` element within a `<p>`.

Comment: This looks like raw HTML. Where is the JavaScript which wraps around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `<span id="timeDisplay">` at the position where you want to display the time.
Then, use `document.getElementById("timeDisplay").innerHTML = timePassed;` to display the value of variable timePassed.

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o1rs2bhm/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need the  tag to use javascript:

```
<p id="time">Your time was: </p>
<script>
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML += timePassed;
</script>
```

I give the `<p>` an id so I can easily access it in JavaScript.

The `document.getElementById` function gets an element (an HTML tag) given its ID. So I tell it to get the element with the id `"time"`, which is the `<p>` element.

Then I append onto the innerHTML (the text inside the `<p>` element) the JavaScript variable `timePassed` - that's the += operator.

Comment: Ok Thank You! Let me try it out

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
  <p>
    Congratulations! You won! Would you like to restart?
    <span class="restart"><i class="fa fa-repeat"></i></span>
    Your time was <span id="time_passed_container"></span>
  </p>
</body>
```

And in your script

```
<script>
  var timePassed = 11;
  document.getElementById("time_passed_container").innerText = timePassed;
</script>
```