# HTML/JS: datetime display-er

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

Is there available a component, a div class, anything which uses pure JS or bootstrap in order to display a date string which formats as per instructions? For example:

```
<div
  class="my-datetime-formatter-and-display-er"
  value="Thu 30 Apr 20:12:08 EEST 2020"
  format="%M/%Y"
></div>
```

and display "04-2020"? But for the same `value`, when format changes it displays something else? The idea is that the `value` is the same all the time.

All I get in my searches are date-pickers.

Alternatively, if I already have a js function which formats a datestr, e.g. `formatdata("Thu 30 Apr 20:12:08 EEST 2020", "%M/%Y")`, how can I call it on a `div` onload(?) to format the value and fill it in at creation time? (provided that it does not interfere with already installed `onclick` etc.)

Comment: Does this help? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: See also [how to display a javascript var in html body](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40858456/215552)

Comment: Heretic Monkey thanks that 2nd link looks promising basically is what @Federico Moretti suggesting. Can it be a bit more opaque and hide details from the user?

Answer (score 1):

Wait, **Bootstrap has nothing to do with it**. Bootstrap can handle how it’s displayed, but it can’t alter the date format (and I can’t see a Bootstrap class in your code): plus, the `<div>` element doesn’t have a `value` attribute by default in HTML. You should use `<date>` instead, eventually with `datetime="Thu 30 Apr 20:12:08 EET 2020"` as an attribute. That said, my suggestion is to manage it by JavaScript.

```
<div class="my-datetime-formatter-and-display-er">
  <date datetime="04-2020">Thu 30 Apr 20:12:08 EET 2020</date>
</div>
```

You can modify the `datetime` or the innerHTML of `<date>` with a JavaScript function, calling the class `.my-datetime-formatter-and-display-er` as a DOM node. You can let the `<date>` element empty and show just its `datetime` attribute as well. Calling your function, if existing, from `onload` depends just on which event listener you choose in JavaScript. I mean, like:

```
window.addEventListener('load', formatData('Thu 30 Apr 20:12:08 EET 2020', '%M-%Y'));
```

…to have it at the window loading event. How to show the date on the page is up to you. I hope this can help you, although I’m not sure I understood your question.

Comment: perhaps I was not clear but I do want to control how it is displayed. Suppose the date value comes from ajax. And fills the div. Now suppose that it comes unformatted and I want as soon as the div senses that the value has changed, to format it using the format and display it like this, formatted.