# I want to catch the value of selected item on change of dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the value of the selected item in dropdown in some variable and use it in my code. I want to use this data for another dropdown next to this list:

```
    <html>
         <head>
         <title>Home Page</title>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
        <body>
        <button id="mybtn">Emp Name</button>
        <div>
        <select id="output">    
         <script>
                 $('#mybtn').click(function () {
                 $.getJSON('empData', function (data) {
                 $("select#output > option").remove();
                 $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                 $("#output").append('<option>' + value['empId'] + " " + value['empName'] +'</option>');                 
                  });
                  });
                  }); 
            </script>
        </select>
        </div>
        </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JavaScript:

```
var o = document.getElementById("output");
var value = o.options[o.selectedIndex].value;
var text = o.options[o.selectedIndex].text;
```

jQuery:

```
$("#output:selected").text(); // The text content of the selected option
$("#output:selected").val(); // The value of the selected option
```

Comment: Can you please also tell me, how to display the selected value on the webpage.

Comment: This would be of help...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858456/how-to-display-a-javascript-var-in-html-body

Answer (score 0):

If its multiple select drop down you have to push your selected values in an array and also when deselect you have to pop the value from an array.Then you can use that array in your another drop down.

use the below code to get the values asusal in drop down:

```
var select = document.getElementById('output');
var value = select.value;
```

this will gives you the selected values.

Comment: Can you please also tell me, how to display the selected  value on the webpage.

Comment: just put the variable in the place where u want ur text to be displayed.

Comment: I could not display the value. Can u please help with full code.