# Unable to print javascript variable text in html inside a react component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm learning a backend administrative dashboard framework callled admin bro. So basically i am trying to make a tooltip component. And this is the code I have tried till now.

```
class Textbox extends React.PureComponent {
 

render() {
    const { property } = this.props;
    
    const ob = this.props.property.name
    const sentence = { 
        first : ' this is the first text ',
        second : ' this is second text',
        third: 'this is third text',
        fourth : 'this is the fourth text',
    }

    
    var line = sentence[ob]
       
    return (
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write(line)
        </script>
    )
  }
}

export default withTheme(Textbox)
```

In this `ob` has the values like first,second, third and fourth, so when it is `sentence[ob]` it means for example sentence[first] (when ob is first) so `line` then gets the corresponding text to it which is 'this is the first text'. I have consoled logged `line` and seen that this part is working perfectly.

Now I just have to display `line` inside the html code inside return.

I have tried to implement `document.write()` from this - [how to display a javascript var in html body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858456/how-to-display-a-javascript-var-in-html-body)

But this doesn't work. What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return method should always have one html parent tag (div in my example). This element can have as many children as you like, but can't have any siblings.

Then you can execute javascript statements by wrapping them in curly braces like so `{javascript goes here}`

So your code should be

```
return(
  <div>{line}</div>
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you start with the [React tutorials](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html), it doesn't seem like you understand the syntax of React at all. In the render() method, you need to return jsx, which looks a lot like HTML but with slight differences. I don't know what you want to return, so I gave an example of what you *can* return, a `div` with the line variable you generated in your code.

Also, you need to note that the render() method runs every time there is an update to the virtual DOM, so you should only place logic in it if it's absolutely necessary.

```
class Textbox extends React.PureComponent {
    const { property } = this.props;
    
    const ob = property.name
    const sentence = { 
        first : ' this is the first text ',
        second : ' this is second text',
        third: 'this is third text',
        fourth : 'this is the fourth text',
    }

    
    var line = sentence[ob]
    render() {   
        return (
           <div className="line">{line}</div>
        )
    }
}

export default withTheme(Textbox)
```

Answer (score 0):

React is using a template syntax called Mustache ({ }) single curly brackets to replace the javascript variable inside JSX element.

After that React does the rendering together with the value that you have binded using the embedded expression.

[Embedding Expressions in JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx)

Comment: he's asking about React so mentioning other libraries here is not really answering the question

Comment: Got it ..yea..should have only mentioned about React