# How to Display Variable content

Tags: html, css, css-variables

Is there a way to display my CSS-Variable's Content to my HTML webpage?
My Variable's name is `--pick-container-width` and its Content is `5vh`.
Now I want (for testing Reasons) to display the Content to an `<h1>` but idk how...

Comment: You would have to use JavaScript to do that. See [Accessing a CSS custom property (aka CSS variable) through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36088655/215552) To get that into HTML, see [how to display a javascript var in html body](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40858456/215552)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing a CSS custom property (aka CSS variable) through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088655/accessing-a-css-custom-property-aka-css-variable-through-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `var()` function. Below is an example.

```css
:root {
  --color: crimson;
}

.title {
  color: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">I am a title tag!</h1>
```