# displaying a date in django template using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm not sure why the date won't display in this django template, using javascript and html:
I've also found this helpful: [how to display a javascript var in html body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858456/how-to-display-a-javascript-var-in-html-body)

But following that, still can't get it to work.
Currently I have:

```
{% extends 'chattr.html' %}

<section class="">
    hello
</section>
    <script>
        let d = new Date();

        document.getElementById("date0").innerHTML = d;
        n =  new Date();
        y = n.getFullYear();
        m = n.getMonth() + 1;
        d = n.getDate();
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = m + "/" + d + "/" + y;
    </script>
<p id="date"></p>
{% block chatStream %}
<b>smallest_steps:</b> <br> 
Hello! Please send me a message:)   <span id="date0"></span>  <br>
<p id="date"></p>
{% endblock %}
```

and chattr.html

```
<h1>ss</h1>
{% block title %}{% endblock %}
{% block chatStream %} {% endblock %}
```

Thanks so much

Comment: Your `<script>` will not render, since it is not part of any block...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks so much -- that makes a ton of sense:)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks again... I moved it into the block, but I'm getting this error now: ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
    at (index):7```... I'm not sure why the date object would be null...

Comment: I think you will need to wrap it in a function that is evaluated if the entire body is loaded, for example wth jQuery through `$(function () { ... })`: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/