# Display the result of a function as variable in a browser using document.getElementbyId.innerHTML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am a newbie to JavaScript < 1 Week old
I wrote a very short HTML/JavaScript and got it to display on console.

Basically, I want to display the result of a function used as a variable inside the `<p>` tag of the HTML.

I got the script to display in the console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var kilo = function(pound) {
  return pound/2.2;
}
kilo (220);
console.log (kilo(220));
</script>
<script>
var kilog = function(pounds) {
  return pounds/2.2;
}
console.log (kilog(440));
</script>
<p id="Kilograms"><!--I want the result here--></p>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I get the result of the function as a variable i.e var kilo (pounds)... to display in the p tag with id Kilograms?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display javascript variables in a html page without document.write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689109/how-to-display-javascript-variables-in-a-html-page-without-document-write)

Comment: And the answers to that question tell you exactly how to do that...

Comment: My apologies Mike, but it is not what I am looking for. I want to use a specific function document.getElementById.innerHTML to write the result of a function as a variable to display on the HTML in the browser.  I got the script to write the result to a console. I want the same result to appear in between the p element tags of the HTML

Comment: At some point, you need to use logic to connect the pieces. That's what programming is. [This answer to that question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16439113/215552) uses a variable `test` to hold what will be inserted. Are you saying you can't figure out how to assign the result of that that function to the variable? Because that's basic programming: `var test = kilo(220);`. Please, do yourself, and SO, a favor and take some introductory classes to programming.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I will try your proposed solution. I just started JavaScript 4 days ago!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script shold be after BODY code, or you should add document ready event listener. So, try this solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="Kilograms"><!--I want the result here--></p>

</body>
<script>
var kilo = function(pound) {
  return pound/2.2;
}
kilo (220);
console.log (kilo(220));

var kilog = function(pounds) {
  return pounds/2.2;
}
console.log (kilog(440));
document.getElementById("Kilograms").innerHTML = kilog(440);
</script>
</html>
```

Example in JSBin: https://jsbin.com/pacovasuve/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me. Got it to work yesterday but you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Done, however I am a newbie with a reputation less than 15 so SO says it will not show up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var p = document.getElementById('Kilograms');
p.innerHtml = 'any text';
// OR
p.innerHtml = kilog(440);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Comment: @Shayan Please, I don't want just any text there, but rather, the result of the function as a variable in there.

Comment: @Zachra I edit my answer, please have a look at that

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your js code.

```
document.getElementById("Kilograms").innerHTML="write whatever you want here";
```

Comment: Commentary with answer is always appreciated.