# How to reference to a variable in HTML file

Tags: html, matlab, variables, parameters, reference

I am using Matlab to try to write a HTML file which looks like this:

```
<HTML><pre>
this is the first line      
this is another line     
this is another line which prints a value: ????  <!--This line must print, instead of the question marks, the value present at the last row of the file-->     
some random stuff ------------------
**reference to this value** <!--This value needs to be prented insead of ???? and does not need to be shown as the last row-->
</HTML>
```

My goal is to print a value (number in this case) instead of `???`. I was thinking that I should have some sort of reference to the value which is not known *a priori*. The value in fact is the result of a calculation after some operations are completed and some random stuff is printed before in the file.

Can you suggest me some intelligent and elegant way to achieve my goal please?

This is what the output in the browser would be like if the value is for example 55:

[image]

Here there is what I have tried so far without success:

```
<HTML><pre>this is the first line      
this is another line     
this is another line which prints a value: <a name="marco" href="#polo" ></a>  <!--This line must print, instead of the question marks, the value present at the last row of the file-->     
some random stuff ------------------
<a param name="polo" href="#marco"> 55 </a>
</HTML>
```

Comment: why downvoting? I connot find the answer to my question anywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML file is still a file. So basically You can render it in many different ways. So there is question number 1: how do You make that file? Second question - that value You are interesting in is available at the moment that file is generated/served or after? If after then You should set that value with JavaScript, this might help [How to display javascript variables in a html page without document.write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689109/how-to-display-javascript-variables-in-a-html-page-without-document-write).

Comment: I have a Matlab script that prints a series of rows... in my example, the second row needs to display a value which is found while some "random stuff" is printed in the file itself. This random stuff may contain an operation that gives a number and needs to be displayed beforehand.

Comment: I would try to make all output first and then dump it into a file when it is ready. I think this should be possible in Matlab.