# Variable values in php are not printing when passing through javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am passing variable through javascript AJAX request but not getting it in php file to print.
JS code:

```
        var build = {
        m_count : (document.getElementById('count').value)
        }
        $.ajax({
        data: build,
        type: "POST",
        url: "tabs.php",
        success: function(data) {

        console.log(data);
        }
        });
```

PHP code :

```
<?php

$module_c= $_POST['m_count'];
echo "module_c";

var_dump($_POST);

?>
```

Output of console.log is weird as it shows whole tabs.php file in console.
And Output of  `var_dump($_POST);`is array(0) { }.
NOt sure where i am getting wrong, please help.. THAnks

Comment: What do you mean by "it shows whole tabs.php file"?  If you're seeing PHP code on the client then your PHP isn't executing.  But you're also claiming to get output from `var_dump`, so it's not clear what problem you're describing.

Comment: what type of element is `document.getElementById('count')`

Comment: Yes @Kurt  thats what it is returning all the html in that php file with this value also array(1) {
  ["m_count"]=>
  string(2) "55" . which is what i am looking for. But the question is why my echo statement is not printing these values.

Comment: @GM-Script-Writer-62850 it is input box type= number. I am getting user input and on click of continue button making a AJAX call to pass that input to php file again .

Comment: @veenu: Well, if there's HTML in that PHP file then it certainly would return that.  You're not showing that in the question, though.  I still don't see what the actual problem is.  You're saying that it's returning the values that the code outputs.  So what's wrong?

Comment: I was wishing it will solve the issue but @Mike its printing the value now in console but not on actual page.

Comment: You are not even being consistent here. You said `var_dump($_POST);` is `array(0) { }`, but then you say `array(1) { ["m_count"]=> string(2) "55"`. Are you sure you don't have multiple `var_dump()`s in your script? Also, `"module_c"` is not the same as `$module_c`, or even `"$module_c"` if it's part of a larger string. That's why it's not printing anything out.

Comment: "*its printing the value now in console but not on actual page*" - You aren't telling it to do that. You're telling it to log to the console. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689109/how-to-display-javascript-variables-in-a-html-page-without-document-write

Comment: @veenu: `"its printing the value now in console but not on actual page"` - What exactly did you think `console.log(data);` was going to do?

Comment: If you're seeing HTML in the console, it means that there's more in `tabs.php` than the code you showed. It's also printing HTML before or after that code.

Comment: @David but why my echo $module_c; isnt working . I want to echo that value to check if it is being passed or not.

Comment: Echoing a variable is the wrong way to check if it's being passed or not. You should instead be using http://php.net/empty in combination with any other sort of validation you want to do.

Comment: @Mike but why it is not printing in php then? I want to check if it is being passed to that file or not as i want to use that variable for other calculations.

Comment: @veenu: Well, you're not echoing a variable value.  You're just echoing the literal string "module_c".  Did you mean to do this?:  `echo $module_c;`

Comment: yes @david that was a mistype in question . I am doing echo $module_c;

Comment: @veenu: So the code in the question isn't the code you're using?  That's going to make it pretty difficult (read: impossible) to help you.  What is the actual code you're using, and what *specifically* is the problem you're seeing?  So far it's been very unclear what you're actually describing, because what you keep telling us is exactly what we'd expect this code to do.

Comment: Click the "Edit" link under your question to add any updates to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to fix. Maybe try these changes to your code: (notice the dataType: "json". This tells AJAX what server is sending back will be JSON.)

```
    var build = {
    m_count : (document.getElementById('count').value)
    }
    $.ajax({
    data: build,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    url: "tabs.php",
    success: function(data) {

    console.log(data);
    }
    });
```

And the tab.php.
Notice json_encode(). Your ajax should want a JSON response, and nothing after. So no var_dump. You can put the POST in your JSON.

```
<?php

$module_c= isset($_POST['m_count']) ? $_POST['m_count'] : 0;
//Now add 5 to count. To test calculation.
$module_c= $module_c + 5;
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode(array("module_c" => $module_c, "POST" => $_POST));

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew Hall. but now i see all the html on the page when i load tabs.php. IN the console it says "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json:

Comment: `var build = {
    m_count : (document.getElementById('count').value)
    }
    $.ajax({
    data: build,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    url: "tabs.php",
    success: function(data) {

    console.log(data);
    }
    },"json");`
Try this

Comment: And in PHP side use `header("Content-type: application/json");`

Comment: If there is HTML after your echo, you should do die(); on line after echo. But you will also need to put it all in if(isset($_POST['m_count'])){}