# How to display a dynamic variable in the title of an html page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working on an html page for some time now and now I want to display the ever changing value of a JavaScript variable after some text in the title. ex: 

___/TEXT :: TEXT: var \ _________ 

If this is possible in JS and html how would I do it. If I have to I am open to a little PHP, but nothing to complicated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689109/how-to-display-javascript-variables-in-a-html-page-without-document-write

Comment: @Munoz the __/ text \ ____ was just an example of how i would want it to look in the browser title. it is not code.

Comment: You need to do some effort to fix it by yourself first, and next ask for a particular issue you've faced: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: request close plz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look over [`Javascript Basics`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-strings-in-javascript)

> Web-crawlers update their indices if your title changes, as a heads-up note.

---

```js
let variable = "-hello world-";

document.title  = "___/TEXT :: TEXT: " + variable + " \ _________";
console.log(document.title);
/*
OR
document.title  = "___/TEXT :: TEXT: var \ _________";
document.title  = document.title.replace('var', variable);
*/
```

Comment: This just looks like changing the text inside of a document. I want to display the variable in the <title> element.

Comment: what does the `let` mean? p.s. I can code in JavaScript but there are still lost of things i don't know about >~<

Comment: Refer to [`What's the difference between using “let” and “var” to declare a variable in JavaScript?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable-in-jav). `let` keyword is a strict scoped variable definition.

Comment: Thanks never knew that. Then if I understood it right then I could use my already defined `var` instead of your `let` variable?

Comment: No problem. :) Make sure to select the best answer to not keep this question hanging.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title

```
let title = 'my new title';
document.title = title;
```