# How to display past user input with HTML

Tags: html, forms, input, display

For a project, I am asked to design a chat bot that answers questions about incident management. I utilized the tutorial in W3schools to create a chat bot, but I want to be able to display the user input above the input box to show the past conversation. I am not sure how to do that with HTML. Basically, after the user asks a question, all their questions (and respective answers) will be displayed above in a chain of messages. I know the question seems silly but I could really use some help. I know I can use jQuery, but I am not familiar with it, so if anyone could walk me through the process it would be great.

I have tried using the `<input>` and `<output>` tags, but I do not think those work. From the pre-existing code, what can I change?

Comment: you want to show previous conversation data without using a database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display JavaScript variables in a HTML page without document.write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689109/how-to-display-javascript-variables-in-a-html-page-without-document-write)

Comment: Yes I want to display what they wrote above the textarea placeholder without a database

Comment: @poojp use local storage, session storage or indexed db Hope it helps =)

Comment: @HereticMonkey the link you sent isn't really helpful sorry

Comment: I'd use JQuery to grab the previous message from the text box when you click the button and use the .html() or .append() feature to add text into an element that you can position on top of it using css.

Comment: @Ahm23 sorry but would you be willing to help me with the jQuery? Where do I input it?

Comment: Before the <body> tag of your document. Add a <head> tag and close it obviously. Inside the <head>, ```<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>``` Now for the rest of your <script> tags with the javascript you can use jQuery functions such as: https://api.jquery.com/append/